# Normalizing Points of a Contour

Tags: points, contour, normalize

How would you guys go about normalizing the points of a contour? I know one method is using the [Intersection of a Line and a Circle](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/sphereline/) algorithm, but are there any other methods for doing this?

Also, what I mean by normalizing the points of a contour is that I want to get equally spaced points on the contour, just to be clear. Thanks!

'-'